# After logging out and redirecting to login screen, if I enter a valid site URL, Laravel logs me back in

Tags: php, laravel

In this particular circumstance my user's credentials are stored in the browser. The default path to redirect to post-login is '/dashboard'.

If the user logs in, and then logs out they are redirected to the login page (as they should be). Then, if instead of pressing login with the pre-filled credentials they decide to go to the URL and append '/dashboard' (suppose they knew the path), Laravel will log them in and take them there. A user must be logged in to access '/dashboard'.

After running many tests this only happens when the user's credentials are saved to the browser. Is this the browser or Laravel trying to be helpful? This seems like incorrect behavior to me.

I have tried using logout as a GET and POST method. 
And the following in LoginController:

```
 /**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $validationList = [
        'email'     => 'required|string',
        'password'  => 'required|string',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $validationList);
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }
}

/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response|void
 * @throws ValidationException
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    Log::emergency('login');
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request))
    {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(new MessageBag([
        'password' => 'The email or password you entered is incorrect.',
    ]));
}

/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (strpos(\session('url.intended'), '/logout') !== FALSE)
        \session()->forget('url.intended');
    $homeGuard = new HomeController();
    $arguments = $homeGuard->getUserRoles();

    if ($arguments['roles']->count() == 1) session(['userRole'=> $arguments['roles']->first()->Role]);
    else return $homeGuard->chooseRoleView($arguments);
}

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => [
        'logout',
        'getLogout',
        'otc.logout',
    ]]);
}

/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Log::emergency('logged out');
    Auth::logout();
    $request->session()->flush();
    return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect()->guest('/login');
}

/**
 * The user has logged out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
{
    \auth()->logout();
    return redirect()->guest('/login');
}
```

As expected, the user is "logged" out when Laravel returns the login view. Does anyone know what could possibly be causing this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried entering the wrong credentials and following the url? Do you have any server-side validation? Does it also kick in in this scenario?

Comment: I do use server-side validation. If the user tries to log in with missing or wrong credentials it will redirect them to log in and display error messages. However, if the credentials are saved to the browser and they append '/dashboard' like in the example, then none of the server-side validation gets triggered because it never even enters the login() method.

Comment: Well without a controller and the login code it's guessing. But I think you still got a cookie or any local storage with correct credentials.

Comment: I will post the login code, it is mostly copy-pasted from the Laravel defaults. Does Laravel save login credentials in cookies? I don't think we do that explicitly in our codebase.

Comment: That means entering the correct credentials before following the link has nothing to do with the problem since you assume the credentials used are those saved in the browser. Apparently, it seems that authentication session isn't cleaned up properly during logout.

Comment: Possibly, but remember that if I try to do the same with credentials that are **not** saved to the browser then it doesn't follow the link and redirects the user to login (as is expected). I have searched around and the two calls I make on logout are Auth::logout() and Session::flush().

Comment: Why are you manually calling `$this->loggedOut()`? It is supposed to be triggered automatically by a logout event.

Comment: @StuiterSlurf I also call window.localStorage.clear() prior to logging out. The reason for this is because I use Vuex and want to make sure the local storage is destroyed.

Comment: @UdoE. that part of the code is copied from AuthenticatesUsers trait.

Comment: @UdoE. from their github: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L141

Comment: @BryanF, rather than copy code from the inbuilt laravel libraries, I'll advise you **extend** the appropriate classes and **use** the appropriate traits to avoid unnecessary bugs and ensure easy maintenance of your code in case of updates. see the official docs here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication). it is pretty clear and understandable.

Comment: I appreciate the advice (it is certainly good advice), but unfortunately the business aspect of the product I have inherited doesn't allow me to rebuild authentication.